# AIX /etc/security/user: what happens if the values in a stanza are specified twice?

Tags: security, unix, aix

I have an /etc/security/user file on AIX and I have a stanza that looks like this:

```
someuser:
expires = 0912154623
account_locked = false


expires = 0116202437
account_locked = false
```

Which of the values takes precedence in this case?  This is an error in the SA's part, but I'm curious how AIX handles this.

Answer (score 1):

It reads the first one and stops, or at least it used to in AIX 5.3.

Comment: Yep - confirmed